# PySide6 program exiting with code 0xC0000409 when using QThread

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside, pyside6

I'm encountering an issue with PySide6 where my program exits with the code 0xC0000409 when using QThread. Additionally, I've noticed that the `__del__` method of `TestWindow` is not being called when the program exits. The strange thing is that the code works as expected with PyQt6.

```py
from PySide6.QtCore import QThread
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
import sys


class TestWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.thread = QThread()
        self.thread.start()
        self.show()

    def __del__(self):
        print("__del__ method called")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = TestWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

In this example, the PySide6 program exits with the code 0xC0000409, while PyQt6 exit normally. Additionally, the `__del__` method of `TestWindow` is not being called when using PySide6, but it works as expected with PyQt6.

Is there a known issue or a specific reason why PySide6 exhibits this behavior, especially when working with QThread? Is there something I need to do differently in PySide6 to address the exit code and ensure proper cleanup?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I get this message when closing the window on PySide 6.5: `QThread: Destroyed while thread is still running`

Comment: You might want to wait for thread to finish its job before destroying it. QMainWindow destructor runs the destructor of QThread which is still running. You need to explicitly quit() or exit() the thread in the destructor and then do a waitForFinished(), then you are safe to destroy the thread object.

Comment: Reimplement the close-event handler for the main window and explicitly quit the thread: `def closeEvent(self, event): self.thread.quit(); self.thread.wait()`. If the thread is running a blocking for-loop or suchlike, you will also need a mechanism to break out of that loop.

Comment: You should never fully rely on calls to `__del__`, not even to "ensure" about memory clean up: 1. when the process ends, the OS will take care of releasing *all* the memory allocated to the program, even if the program didn't exit gracefully; 2. if the program/interpreter is hung, `__del__` wouldn't be called anyway (and that would be the least of your concerns); 3. from the [`__del__` docs](//docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__): "It is not guaranteed that __del__() methods are called for objects that still exist when the interpreter exits."; 4. if python "crashes", »

Comment: » then no `__del__` can be called; 5. different python/Qt version may lead to different behavior; 6. the lifespan of Qt objects and their relative Python references don't always match: a Qt object may be destroyed while its python reference may still be valid (possibly causing an exception when trying to call its Qt functions), or the python reference can be deleted while the Qt object still exists (like widgets created with local variables and then added to a layout); you could get a `__del__` even if the Qt object still exists, or you could *not* get it when the Qt object is destroyed.